# Set Values in Generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I have a generic method that I want to pass a variable to, and if that variable is IEnumerable, set all its elements to its default value. This is what I have so far:

```
public static T set_to_default<T>(T the_obj)
{
    var the_enumerable = the_obj as IEnumerable;
    if (the_enumerable != null)
    {
        foreach (var element in the_enumerable)
        {
            // I don't know what to put here
            // I want to set each element to its default value: default(T)
        }
        return the_obj;
    }
    else
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

What do I put inside the *foreach* loop?

Comment: An `IEnumerable` doesn't support "setting" its values because it doesn't necessarily represent concrete storage.  Do you mean `ICollection`?  As it is, I think `the_enumerable.Cast<object>().Select(item => default(T))` will do what you want, though that's not modifying the input object.

Comment: What is this method supposed to do if you pass as argument the result of [`Enumerable.Range(1, 10)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range)?

Comment: Please clarify if you need code that specifically _modifies_ `the_obj` or if creating and returning a new collection _based on_ `the_obj` is acceptable.  Three times in your question you mention "set"ing "values" or "elements" plus your stub code `return`s `the_obj`, which sounds to me like you want the contents of `the_obj` to be changed.  Your question is currently unclear without this clarification.

Comment: @BACON ideally the method would set all the elements in the_obj to default(T), without creating a new object.

Comment: Ok, but you understand that there's no way to set the elements of an [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) that is not also either an [`IList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) or an [`ICollection<>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) because the `IEnumerable` interface (and `IEnumerable<>`, for that matter) simply doesn't support modifications, yes?  Do you know if you'll ever be handling such input objects?  If so, you have to return a new `IEnumerable` in their place.

Comment: @BACON that's why I asked the question

Answer (score 3):

You should just work with overloads, it's much simpler (if I understand your question correctly).

```
public static T SetToDefault<T>(T the_obj)
{
    return default(T);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> SetToDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T> the_enumerable)
{
    return the_enumerable.Select(value => default(T));
}
```

FYI I tested my code with this function:

```
public static void Test()
{
    int myInt = 7;
    IEnumerable<int> myEnumberable = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 8, 9 };

    myInt = SetToDefault(myInt);
    myEnumberable = SetToDefault(myEnumberable);

    Console.WriteLine($"MyInt: {myInt}");
    Console.WriteLine($"MyEnumberable: {String.Join(", ", myEnumberable)}");
}
```

To add to this, keep in mind that the name `SetToDefault` isn't a great choice. When you pass in an int, you will get back an int. You still have to set the value yourself (`myInt = SetToDefault(myInt);`) which is kind of contradictory to what the name of the function implies.

By the way, note that the first function (`T SetToDefault<T>(T the_obj)`) has a parameter which is never used. To work around this (to be fair, small) issue, you could use an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static T GetDefault<T>(this T value) {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Note that even here, you will have to set the value to the return of the function. Returning `void` and simply doing `value = default(T);` **will not work** for primitive types like `int`. That's also why I named it `GetDefault` instead of `SetToDefault` this time.

```
var myWhatever = 3.4;
myWhatever = myWhatever.GetDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop put the following statement:

```
var default_val = Activator.CreateInstance(element.GetType());
```

This is how you set to default value

and here is a complete working example of your program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var my_list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        var list2 = set_to_default<List<int>>(my_list);
        foreach (var elem in list2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static T set_to_default<T>(T the_obj)
    {
        IEnumerable the_enumerable = the_obj as IEnumerable;
        if (the_enumerable != null)
        {
            Type type = the_enumerable.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });
            IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

            var looper = the_enumerable.GetEnumerator();

            while (looper.MoveNext())
            {
                var current_obj = looper.Current;
                current_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(current_obj.GetType());
                list.Add(current_obj);


            }

            return (T)list;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest to use lists instead of enumerables because the last ones are immutable. That is once you create them you cannot edit them.

Final thing....if you want to support other types of IEnumerable the are not IList you may use the C# 'is' keyword to figure it out. In this case you need to know the underlying type of your enumerable at run-time. You may do that using the C# 'is' keyword

```
            if (the_enumerable is IList)
            {
                editableType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });
            }
            else if(the_enumerable is ICollection)
            {
                ......
            }
```

Comment: But then what do you do with `default_val`?  That's a local variable; how do you assign that value to `the_enumerable`?  Also, this would be constructing a `T`, whereas the comment in the question wants `default(T)`, which would be `null`, not an instance, for a reference type.

Comment: I suggest to use lists instead of enumerables because the last ones are immutable. That is once you create them you cannot edit them.

Comment: in case you do not want to get "null" as the default value of object, you need to call its constructor  dynamically like the example below
        Type type = typeof(Addition);
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
        object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { 10 });

Comment: But that works because you _know_ your test code is passing a `List<>`.  If you're going to make that assumption you might as well just cast it to `List<>` and not bother with `IEnumerable`.  The question is about handling `IEnumerable` input.  What happens when you pass an `IEnumerable` that is not a `List<>`?

Comment: In this case you need to know the underlying type of your enumerable at run-time. You may do that using the C# 'is' keyword

                if (the_enumerable is IList)
                {
                    editableType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });
                }